# how to handle when either of view or partial view fails with global handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have implemented global error handler using exceptionfilter in my application. This global handler finds and loads error message to temp data. The application have error control to show these error messages from tempdata. This works fine when any of my partial control fails.But when entire view fails, there is no view to show error control as the view had error and hence the 500 Internal error is shown in the browser.

To avoid this I tried using . I specified defaultRedirect. I have defined a route for the same and then implemented an action on controller. But the problem is this won’t work as the global handler gets called on exception, this global handler sets the ExceptionHandled=true.

Now If I don’t mark ExceptionHandled=true, then the Action mentioned in defaultRedirect gets invoked. This is fine if entire view fails.But when a partial view fails then also the error view will always be shown since ExceptionHandled is not set in error handler so it default redirects as well.

Please suggest me how this can be tackled. I want the error control to display on page when partial control fails and want to show error view when entire view fails.

Please revert soon.
.